# Bootstrap input-group button is right aligned

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How can I align the search button to be next to the search box?

Code is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputLoginSearch">Search for HOA</label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input id="inputLoginSearch" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter search phrase">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit - added full markup of page

```
<div id="mainDiv" runat="server" class="panel-body">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Standard Login</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <%-- Start of Standard Login--%>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div id="StandardLoginForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                        <fieldset>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputLoginSearch">Search for HOA</label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input id="inputLoginSearch" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter search phrase">
                                                        <span class="input-group-btn" >
                                                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Search</button>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="select">HOA</label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="select">
                                                        <option>1</option>
                                                        <option>2</option>
                                                        <option>3</option>
                                                        <option>4</option>
                                                        <option>5</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputUserName">User Name</label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="inputUserName" type="text" placeholder="User Name">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">

                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <%--End of Standard Login--%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">HOA Manager Integrated Login</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <%-- Start of Standard Login--%>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            <%--End of Standard Login--%>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
```

If I create a brand new 'out of the box' WebForms project in VS2013 the same thing happens. Also form-vertical makes a complete mess of everything, only form-horizontal works.

Comment: In default Bootstrap css this is aligned http://jsbin.com/hodeqo/1/ -- you have other css doing that

Comment: The only other css file is site.css (default when the project is created) - I excluded that from the project and ran it again - same issue

Comment: Agree with @Christina, you either have some custom CSS or a customised Bootstrap. As this shows, your code looks fine http://www.bootply.com/S12VGY7DCx

Comment: I'm inclined to think you have a `width` or `max-width` property on your input somewhere, not that the button is right aligned.

Comment: Also, we don't know the wrapper used on this form. What class, if any? If it's a stacked form, there's no class on the form element

Comment: I did add the page markup

Comment: In both bootstrap 3.2 and 3.3 and 3.0 this formats correctly: http://jsbin.com/hodeqo/2/edit?html,output -- since you haven't shown any css, there's something else going on with other css. Remove the other css file AND clear your browser's cache and restart the browser for good measure.

Comment: I would suspect that @DavidG is correct you have something going on with inputs that are fixing the widths because all .form-control is the full width of the parent

Comment: DavidG - you were bang on the money. Even though I excluded Site.css from the project it was included in Bundle.config - the default is to set inputs text, password, email, tel, select to max-width: 280px. If you enter that as the answer I can vote it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DavidG was right about the issue - the problem was removing the max-width for inputs made them spread right across the entire page - so the workaround I found was to leave the max-width in, and just change the input-group div to a max-width (allowing for the button) and then setting in the input at width:100%;

This seems to work well.

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputLoginSearch">Search for HOA</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 358px;">
            <input id="inputLoginSearch" runat="server" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter search phrase" style="width: 100%;"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="SearchButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-info" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```